# Determine the difference between values in object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, lookup

I have the following object and array of numbers. How can I tell which number in the array does not exist as an id in the object? In the following example, I would want 1453.

```
[
  {id: 60, itemName: 'Main Location - 1100 Superior Road - Cleveland'}
  {id: 1456, itemName: 'Third Location - 107,West 20th Street,Manhattan - New York'}
]

[60, 1453, 1456]
```

Comment: You could create a `Map` of IDs of all the objects and then iterate over the array of IDs and check if the current id exists in the `Map`: `if (idMap.has(currentId) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an IDs list of the existing data IDs using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and then use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const data = [
  {id: 60, itemName: 'Main Location - 1100 Superior Road - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1456, itemName: 'Third Location - 107,West 20th Street,Manhattan - New York'}
]

const ids = [60, 1453, 1456];
const dataIDs = data.map(ob => ob.id);  // [60, 1456]
const notExistentIDs = ids.filter(id => !dataIDs.includes(id));

console.log(notExistentIDs);  // [1453]
```

which will return an Array of all the Object IDs (from `data`) not listed in your reference `ids` Array.

Comment: Since there is already an additional `data` mapping task it might be more useful to create a `Set` instance instead of another array. One then could look up the `id`s directly from the set instead of creating a nested loop via `includes`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger absolutely great points you made there. `Set` *is* a better way to tackle this problem, specially on large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the help! My datasets aren't that large

Answer (score 3):

For a grater amount of data-items and a grater amount of `id`s I would choose an approach which creates a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) based lookup via [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping each of an `itemList` item's `id`...

```js
const idLookup = new Set(itemList.map(({ id }) => id));
```

Looking up items directly from a `Set` or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance is much faster than e.g. iterating again and again an array via [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for each iteration step of an outer [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) task.

Filtering a list of non matching item-`id`s then is as straightforward as ...

```js
const listOfNonMatchingIds = idList.filter(id => !idLookup.has(id));
```

... example code ...

```js
const itemList = [
  { id: 60, itemName: 'Main Location - 1100 Superior Road - Cleveland' },
  { id: 1456, itemName: 'Third Location - 107,West 20th Street,Manhattan - New York' },
];
const idList = [60, 1453, 1456];

const idLookup = new Set(itemList.map(({ id }) => id));
const listOfNonMatchingIds = idList.filter(id => !idLookup.has(id));

console.log({ listOfNonMatchingIds });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Beautiful idea for using a Set! This is far more performant than using `.includes()` within every iteration. Intended on using a similar example but was short on time to provide.

Answer (score 2):

[@Roko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76738780/12834972) is absolutely correct and probably a lot faster. Here's my alternative approach using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const data = [
  { id: 60, itemName: "Main Location - 1100 Superior Road - Cleveland" },
  { id: 1456, itemName: "Third Location - 107,West 20th Street,Manhattan - New York" }
];
const ids = [60, 1453, 1456];

const result = ids.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
  data.some(d => d.id === curr) ? acc : [...acc, curr], []
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: no need for reduce, you can still just use `filter` with a nested `some`