# Determine if object property includes array value

Tags: javascript

Given the following array

```
[60, 1456]
```

How can I determine which items in this object do not have a corresponding id to the numbers in the array?

```
[
  {id: 60, itemName: 'Main Location - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1453, itemName: 'Second Location - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1456, itemName: 'Third Location - New York'}
]
```

Comment: `filter()` and `includes()` ? Please show us your attempt....

Comment: Also, it's not 'which items in this object' but 'which objects in this array'.

Comment: I don't have any attempts because I don't know how to do it. Thanks though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Why does the OP ask almost the same question on exactly the same subject as already 3 days before ... [_"Determine the difference between values in object and array"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76738740/determine-the-difference-between-values-in-object-and-array) .., especially since the OP already did accept an answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the `id`  does not (`!`) exists in the `ids` array:

```js
const ids = [60, 1456];
const data = [
  {id: 60, itemName: 'Main Location - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1453, itemName: 'Second Location - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1456, itemName: 'Third Location - New York'}
];

const res = data.filter(({ id }) => !ids.includes(id));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try combination of filter & includes or filter & find or filter indexOf

const a = [60, 1456];

const b = [
  {id: 60, itemName: 'Main Location - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1453, itemName: 'Second Location - Cleveland'},
  {id: 1456, itemName: 'Third Location - New York'}
];

const idExists = b.filter(ob => {
 // const includes = !a.includes(ob.id);
 const find = a.find(id => id !== ob.id);

  return find;
})
```

// Efficient approach

```
const mapOfIds = a.reduce(acc, id => {...acc, [id]: id}, {});
const idExists = b.filter(ob => !mapOfIds[ob.id]);
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted? Calling `find` **for each** item in the array is incredibly inefficient....

Comment: With includes also we are internally iterating on array for each item & with indexOf as well

Comment: Added efficient approach as well